# Gas estimation failed only in mumbai testnet not in VM environment

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, gas-estimate

[image]

When I am calling a specific function I get this error. In Remix IDE, when I deploy and test the contract in a development environment like VM London, It is working without an error. I have tested many times with same and different states and It worked, It uses about 400k gas to run that function. However, when I deploy it in mumbai and make the same test I get this error. What could be the reason for this? The function I am calling is forceFinalizeRound().

```
        function forceFinalizeRound() external onlyOwner{
            uint randomIndex = randomStatusByRound[round.current()].randomIndex;
            address winner = playersByRoundId[round.current()][randomIndex];

            
            players[winner][round.current()].status = PlayerStatus.WIN;
            players[winner][round.current()].earned = calculatePrize();
            players[winner][round.current()].updatedAt = block.timestamp;
            
            raffle[round.current()].status = GameStatus.FINISHED;
            raffle[round.current()].winner = winner;
            token.transfer(winner, calculatePrize()); 
            token.transfer(address(treasuryAddress), getBalance());
            
            finishRound(winner);
        }
```

```
    function finishRound(address winner) internal {
        emit RoundFinished(winner, raffle[round.current()].prizePool, block.timestamp);
        
        if(!isPaused()){
            resetLottery(); 
        }
    }
```

```
    function resetLottery() internal {
        
        address lastRoundWinner = raffle[round.current()].lastRoundWinner;
        uint lastRoundPrizePool = raffle[round.current()].lastRoundPrizePool;

        round.increment();
        raffle[round.current()] = RaffleInfo(block.timestamp + nextRoundInfo.interval,nextRoundInfo.interval,round.current(),nextRoundInfo.ticketPrice,address(0),0,GameStatus.IN_PROGRESS,lastRoundWinner,lastRoundPrizePool,0,nextRoundInfo.entryFees);
        awaitingRandomness=false;
        PRIZE_PERCENTAGE = NEXT_ROUND_PRIZE_PERCENTAGE;
        RaffleInfo memory raffleInfo = raffle[round.current()];
        emit RoundStart(raffleInfo.round, block.timestamp, raffleInfo.interval, raffleInfo.endTime);
    }
```

As I mentioned, It is working in local network and I checked dependent variables like randomIndex,playersByRoundID. They are all correct but it just gives this error. Also I am sure it is not a bug related to remix because I am using Chainlink Automation with internal version of this function and Chainlink also fails to perform this function.

Comment: Did you try calling it from the polygon scan?

Comment: Can you share the source code and contract address? If it works in other chains the problem isn't in the source but the contract state. Check if there are differences in the deployment process, or address involved, e.g. don't use addresses from mainnet in other chains, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Solidity `^0.8.21` uses EVM `"Shanghai"` which introduces PUSH0: a new opcode included in bytecode. This is not supported by mumbai testnet.

Solution is to simply switch your EVM to the previous version named `"Paris"`.

On remix you can do that from the compiler options by selecting a Solidity version prior to `0.8.19` or manually changing your pragma statement on your contract.

Hope this helps!